# Как открыть jquery dialog, если он храниться отдельным файлом, с использованием jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Собственно вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Решено:

```
$( '#блок куда грузим' ).load( "загружаемый контент.html" ).dialog();
```